# Is it possible to affect mobile browser contents with an Android app?

Tags: android, browser, google-chrome-extension

I'm starting to build an Android app with my limited knowledge and I'm not sure if this functionality is possible, but hopefully the great minds at SO can help though!

The basic functionality of the app would be similar to the user entering a text string such as "Chicago Bulls" into the app and then when they're using their mobile browser, all instances of that text string on a page are formatted into bold font and red letters for example.

Is this possible with an Android app at all? Or something similar?

I Googled for building Android apps integrating with mobile browsers, but I wasn't able to find anything relevant. I thought that potentially I could build a mobile Chrome extension, but it looks like Chrome Extensions aren't supported by Android yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear your question. I assume that you want to change some font within webview? If so then you can try

Example:

a) Init you webview

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

b) Create you won stylesheet and attach to html body

```
String pish = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: 
MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/BMitra.ttf\")}body {font-family: 
MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
String pas = "</body></html>";
```

c) Load on webview

```
String webContent = pish + YourTxext + pas;
String internalFilePath = "file://" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(internalFilePath, webContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Yes, so when I open up Chrome browser on my phone, my app would apply certain CSS to the text string specified. I'll try this code when I get home. Thanks Farid!